# How babel and JSX related or differ?

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

I am learning on React JS and I have got information on JSX and babel. But I am not getting clarity on how these are helping React and how these or differ from each other

Comment: JSX + BABEL  = JS , babel compiles jsx to js

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**React JS**

while building an app using React, you can create the components/views in two ways

- using standard React object and methods
- using JSX

**JSX**

- JSX is a separate technology from React and completely optional while building React application, however it makes life much easier when you combine JSX with React.

Let's see how :

**Approach 1 : standard React way**

```
(function() {

    var element = React.DOM.div({}, "Hello World");

    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("app"));

})();
```

The above code can be found [at this link](https://github.com/rabibiswal/reactdemo/tree/master/hello-world).

Here, you just need to include the `react` and `react-dom` library to your page.
Nothing else is required. No JSX, no Babel.

**Approach 2 : JSX way**

```
(function() {

    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({

        render : function() {
            return (
            <div> Hello World </div>
            );
        }
    });

    var element = React.createElement(HelloWorld, {});

    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("app"));

})();
```

The above code can be found [at this link](https://github.com/rabibiswal/reactdemo/tree/master/hello-world-jsx).

Note the difference here: `<div> Hello World </div>` is used inside JavaScript. This is called JSX syntax.

Now, compare the JSX approach with the vanilla JavaScript approach:

With JSX, You can add many more **HTML like elements** inline, just like standard HTML, to create the view layer.

Without JSX, the code can get messy because of the multiple layers of elements required to create HTML in JavaScript.

**Babel**

Now the question is, who understands JSX?.
Here We need a **transpiler**  that understands JSX and converts it to a format that can run on browser. Babel does just this job.

**Transpiling**

Transpiling can be done two ways

1. Browser based/client side transpiling (use only for development
   purpose)

   - include this file as a script tag

   - use `type="text/babel"` on your script tag which loads your JSX

Here's the [sample code](https://github.com/rabibiswal/reactdemo/tree/master/hello-world-jsx)

2. Server based transpiling - e.g. Babel

You can use different tools like webpack etc.

Here's some [sample code](https://github.com/rabibiswal/reactdemo/tree/master/hello-world-react-es5).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Answer looks more convincing but i want one more clarification, if I am using JSX , I should use babel to convert its JSX syntax into browser understandable format. In case I am creating without JSX then babel is not required?

Comment: that's true. you don't need babel when not using JSX, you just need browser.js (which is part of babel core, look at the js file - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js ) , But keep in mind, if you are using es6, you need Babel. Babel is not only a JSX transpiler, it is also es6 transpiler.

Comment: Thank you. It is goo to use babel than JSX Transform. :-)

Comment: @Rabi  is webpack an alternative for Babel transpiler?

Comment: @Dinesh - no, webpack is not an alternative to Babel. Babel is a transpiler (JSX, ES6) where as webpack is a module bundler. You can use babel within webpack configuration to do transpiling. look at this - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

Comment: You can use `<HelloWorld />` instead of `element`

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr;

*JSX* is an easy syntax to represent markup in your code, which Babel converts to pure JavaScript.

## Long version:

*JSX* is a syntactical convention which aims to make element structure definition easier in a React Component's code. This XHTML-like syntax which you write inside your components gets converted into JavaScript (not very different from [Hyperscript](https://github.com/dominictarr/hyperscript)) by Babel.

A very simple Hello World component written in JSX:

```
class HelloWorld extends Component{
    render(){
        return <div><h1>Hello World!</h1></div>
    }
}
```

And the equivalent in pure JavaScript:

```
class HelloWorld extends Component{
    render(){
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement(
                "h1",
                null,
                "Hello World!"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Do note that the above example is abbreviated to keep the focus on the JSX part.

You would soon learn that Babel actually lends a lot more power to the React world than mere JSX transpilation. It allows you to use a lot of cool new ES6/7 features right now.