# Where does JSX come from?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and I see something named JSX.

I'm curious to know where JSX comes from. I know Babel compiles JSX to regular JS so browsers can understand the code, but I would like to know who enables us to write JSX in the first place. Is it from React or Babel?

Comment: You don't have to use React with JSX or vice versa, but there's [a Babel preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) that takes JSX and converts it to the appropriate React API calls. JSX itself is just *"an XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript without any defined semantics"*; see e.g. https://facebook.github.io/jsx/.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41713966/3001761

Answer (score 0):

JSX is a syntax extension to JavaScript. JSX comes with React but JSX is not a requirement for using React. So, anything you can do with JSX can also be done with just plain JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

JSX is a javascript extension, and is recommended by ReactJS. A good resource can be found on the ReactJS site itself: [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#jsx) and [JSX explained](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

That site in general, excellently maintained, is one of the best resources you have available for learning ReactJS.

The Babel site does tell you what it is for, this page in particular: [What is Babel?](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/index.html)